# Faulty splash screen on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

When I launched my game on my iPad, the screen first displayed a faulty splash image with a black lower half momentarily, before displaying the normal splash image.

No matter what I tried, I couldn't get rid of this faulty 'pre-splash image'. I have tried the following:

1) Entered my Plus package serial number and updated my seat in Unity.

2) Deleted and left all splash images blank in Unity.

3) Checked all the LaunchScreen-XXX.png images in XCode.

4) Checked the files referenced by Images.xcassets in Xcode.

5) Changed all the above images to a completely black image. Still, the old faulty picture would appear.

6) Cleared all the data and installation files on my iPad.

7) Deleted General > Launch Images Source.

8) Changed the bundle identifier.

I wonder where XCode kept the faulty image.

I am using Unity 5.5.1 and Xcode 9.2.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted the iPad and now it is working! I guess the issue had to do with the memory cache.